# Three "Keep open"s and it still closes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

This is about review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/close/3161 and this related [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/16398/drupal-placing-code-php-within-the-drupal-system-as-well-as-css)

I check the review history every now and again just for my own sanity. (Making sure I've made the right decision.)

I look at the above review and notice that even though there were three keep open requests It got closed after two more close votes.I was under the impression three keep open votes would stop it from being closed.

I think the history of the question had it so there was no code but had some added after. When I got to the question I could see that and voted to keep it open.

I've now gone and voted to reopen but I can't see how the Close votes won since the keep open votes got to three before the close votes got to four? (unless I'm mistaken and there needs to be four reopen votes?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What the “Keep open” votes do is not as straightforward as that. It's explained in detail in [this answer at meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134673/130186).

In short, “Keep open” votes don't count against the “Close” votes, but 3 of them remove a question from the review queue. That doesn't prevent the answer from being closed by the same 5 “Close” votes as always, but it does make it less likely.

Comment: You mean four close votes?

Comment: I thought it took 5 votes. And [the page about close votes](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) does say that too. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Does that make it broken?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. Those 4 votes are only those that were added through the review queue. So, the initial vote (by mseancole) isn't listed there.